# Python Map function to clean html tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a data frame with following column

```
 description
0   1221    <p>Ê</p><p align="center">Ê<strong><u>Property and Casualty Sales Agent </u></strong></p><p><strong>WHY WORK FOR METLIFE AUTO & HOME</strong><strong><sup>¨</sup></strong><strong>? </strong></p><p><strong>If you want a career that has the reach to affect people everywhere, this is the place to be. At MetLife Auto & Home, weÕre experts in providing products and services that allow our customers to enjoy life and build safety nets they can count on. WeÕre committed to extending the same unmatch...
1   1522    <p>Ê</p><p align="center">Ê<strong><u>Property and Casualty Sales Agent </u></strong></p><p align="center">Ê</p><p><strong>WHY WORK FOR METLIFE AUTO & HOME</strong><strong><sup>¨</sup></strong><strong>? </strong></p><p>Ê</p><p><strong>If you want a career that has the reach to affect people everywhere, this is the place to be. At MetLife Auto & Home, weÕre experts in providing products and services that allow our customers to enjoy life and build safety nets they can count on. WeÕre committe...
```

I want to clean this job description column only keeping the text and removing the html tags.

For this I created a mapper function like below:

```
def html_parsing(x): 
    """ This function takes the input text and cleans the HTML tags from it

    """

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    textcleaned=''
    #if row['desc'] is not None: 
    souptext=BeautifulSoup(x)
    p_tags=souptext.find_all('p')
    for p in p_tags: 
        if p.string:
            textcleaned+=p.string
    #print textcleaned
    return text_cleaned
```

Then I create a new column and pass this map function to that.

```
job_description["cleaned_jd"]=map(html_parsing,job_description["description"])
```

But it gives me a map object as result in the new column and not the cleaned text.

```
description cleaned_jd
0   1221    <p>Ê</p><p align="center">Ê<strong><u>Property and Casualty Sales Agent </u></strong></p><p><strong>WHY WORK FOR METLIFE AUTO & HOME</strong><strong><sup>¨</sup></strong><strong>? </strong></p><p><strong>If you want a career that has the reach to affect people everywhere, this is the place to be. At MetLife Auto & Home, weÕre experts in providing products and services that allow our customers to enjoy life and build safety nets they can count on. WeÕre committed to extending the same unmatch... <map object at 0x1127a5c88>
```

Any idea what went wrong? And if there is a simpler way to do this without beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems you have naming issues inside your def. I had to tie up the textcleaned variable.

```
description =['<p>Ê</p><p align="center">Ê<strong><u>Property and Casualty Sales Agent </u></strong></p><p><strong>WHY WORK FOR METLIFE AUTO & HOME</strong><strong><sup>¨</sup></strong><strong>? </strong></p><p><strong>If you want a career that has the reach to affect people everywhere, this is the place to be. At MetLife Auto & Home, weÕre experts in providing products and services that allow our customers to enjoy life and build safety nets they can count on. WeÕre committed to extending the same unmatch...',
'<p>Ê</p><p align="center">Ê<strong><u>Property and Casualty Sales Agent </u></strong></p><p align="center">Ê</p><p><strong>WHY WORK FOR METLIFE AUTO & HOME</strong><strong><sup>¨</sup></strong><strong>? </strong></p><p>Ê</p><p><strong>If you want a career that has the reach to affect people everywhere, this is the place to be. At MetLife Auto & Home, weÕre experts in providing products and services that allow our customers to enjoy life and build safety nets they can count on. WeÕre committe...']

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def html_parsing(x): 
    """ This function takes the input text and cleans the HTML tags from it

    """

    text_cleaned=''
    souptext=BeautifulSoup(x)
    p_tags=souptext.find_all('p')
    for p in p_tags: 
        if p.string:
            text_cleaned+=p.string
    return text_cleaned


print (list(map(html_parsing,description)))
```

My suggestion was though with the previous comment to use soup.text:

```
[section.text for section in map(BeautifulSoup, description)]
```

Comment: That doesn't help

Comment: Ok. So i had cleaned the naming issue which I realized later too. But I was getting the output as map object as you see in the question and not the cleaned text. You have used a list on map. Why do we need that? I guess map returns the data structure returned by the mapper function?

Comment: List is there just to show you the content, it unwraps the iterator returned by map. It is not needed nor advised in production code.